# Display one-page interactive PDF in a web page using a minimal viewer without widgets

Tags: html, pdf

I tried several ways of displaying a single-page PDF: iframe, object etc. I did not try pdf.js because it is not clear to me if a special server side code is needed. However, all those solutions show the PDF in quite a heavy browser, by default the zoom is too small, there is a gray background that looks bad in my page, a menu bar which I do not want. Then, there are several problems with responsive scaling. Some solutions do not work sensibly because **my PDF is a single, very long page**.

What I would want instead, is the single-page PDF to be displayed directly in a DIV, just like any other image would. Is it possible, preferably with client-side code only? It does not need to be PDF, as I could convert it off-line to any other scalable form. Yet, I do not know a reliable method of converting a PDF to, for example, a SVG, which has no problems with interactivity of links.

Comment: "I did not try pdf.js because it is not clear to me if a special server side code is needed." No, nothing special needed. pdf.js is pure client side.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I tried it and it works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ryan said, pdfjs does not need server side. I tried `PDFSinglePageViewer` with `PDFLinkService`: text selection, external and internal links worked correctly.

There are some tutorials on this, but the installation/initialisation instructions assume some general knowledge about the structure of pdfjs, being in effect somewhat vague to me, so I will describe how I finally did that part. Firstly, I downloaded from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/`, which was the latest version, four files: `pdf_viewer.css`, `pdf_viewer.css`, `pdf_viewer.js` and `pdf.worker.min.js`. After linking `pdf_viewer.css` and executing the following two scripts, the access variables and the worker can be set as follows:

```
const pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
const pdfjsViewer = window['pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.min.js';
```

I made the following container for the pdf page to view:

```
<div id="pdf-wrapper" style="width: 1000px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
</div>
```

which can be accessed in JS as follows:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#pdf-wrapper');
```

Having set these variables, you may just copy and adapt the code from several tutorials about `PDFSinglePageViewer` to be found on the web. The cmaps:

```
var CMAP_URL = "../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/cmaps/";
var CMAP_PACKED = true;
```

aren't necessary for many new PDFs. You may test this on your PDF and if this is the case, just comment out everything related to cmaps.

Some of the tutorial sources contain the line:

```
 // We can use pdfSinglePageViewer now, e.g. let's change default scale.
 pdfSinglePageViewer.currentScaleValue = "page-width";
```

which makes the viewer fill the div.

On both Chrome and Firefox, the viewer had no performance problems with a page this long, yet canvas size limit within pdfjs itself may make the render blurry. It is possible, though, to change that limit in the sources.